# How to stimulate recently-planted grass sod to send up new shoots

Tags: lawn, grass

Well, it's September here in Texas and still in the high 90s and low 100s.  About 2 months ago a landscaper friend gave me about 2 palettes of `Bermuda Celebration` sod and 2 palettes of `St. Augustine` sod.  The St. Augustine was green but the Bermuda was leftover from a job and pretty much yellow.

So I've watered both faithfully (no fertilizer so far), and the St. Augustine has gotten bright green and green shoots have popped out of the Bermuda thatch (it's starting to look lawn-like finally), but I'm wanting both to fill in the areas that have no shoots, i.e. "thicken up".  I just cut the St. Augustine to 3" and the Bermuda to about 2 1/4".

So two questions: 1) Can someone help me to understand what is happening at this point?  My understanding is that now after mowing the roots are more than the top greenery (shoots), and my thought is that that would push the rhizomes to shoot up in new places.  Is this correct or is there another thing that will cause new shoots 2) what else can I do at this time of year, including fertilizer or topsoil, to increase the shoot locations (in other word thicken it)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just keep watering. Both will stop growing in cool or cold weather so I think it is late to fertilize although a garden shop will try to sell you fertilizer.I have not needed to edge ( cut runners) for a couple weeks so I doubt there will be much new rhizome growth this year. You should consider over seeding with annual rye in November.It will keep the lawn green all winter; although then you need to mow in the winter. And rye will die in the heat. The St Augustine will crowd-out the Bermuda where they come in contact ( during summer weather).

Comment: Haha define cool or cold weather.  When the high day temp gets down to 90 or below that will be amazing - probably another 3-4 weeks.  I guess if I fertilize it will be very lightly.  Glad the St Augustine will win, it's preferred.

Comment: Well  , not cool weather here in TX, but maybe hours of daylight. Leaves are falling although temp is in 90's.

Comment: good point, thanks.  Ah, more raking.